# How to change the column values of a DataFrame into title case in scala .

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe

Input Dataframe

```
val ds = Seq((1,"play framework"),
  (2,"spark framework"),
  (3,"spring framework ")).toDF("id","subject")
```

I am expecting **title case** on column **subject** like as follows .

```
 val ds = Seq((1,"Play Framework"),
  (2,"Spark Framework"),
  (3,"Spring Framework ")).toDF("id","subject")
```

I could use Use lower function from **org.apache.spark.sql.functions**

like `ds.select($"subject", lower($"subject")).show`

to convert into lower case . But how i can make a result as i expected as above ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

there is a *inbuilt function* called `initcap` which does exactly as you require

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
ds.withColumn("subject", initcap(col("subject"))).show(false)
```

the [official documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/functions.html#initcap-org.apache.spark.sql.Column-) says it

> > `public static Column initcap(Column e)
> >     Returns a new string column by converting the first letter of each word to uppercase. Words are delimited by whitespace.`

Comment: Can you tell using a user defined function or a built in function will give same performance ?

Comment: inbuilt functions are optimized and works on a column based. while user defined functions works on row wise and requires each selected elements in the row to be serialized and deserialized so inbuilt function performs much better than udf and I always recommend inbuilt function to udf function

Answer (score 1):

You can do like this

```
val captalizeUDF=udf((str:String)=>str.split(" ").map(word=>word.trim.capitalize).mkString(" "))

ds.select($"id",captalizeUDF($"subject").alias("subject")).show

                     or

ds.select($"id",initcap($"subject").alias("subject")).show
```

Sample output:

```
+---+----------------+
| id|         subject|
+---+----------------+
|  1|  Play Framework|
|  2| Spark Framework|
|  3|Spring Framework|
+---+----------------+
```

Comment: Ramesh, Explained very well.

Comment: @Manoj Kumar Dhakd , assume columns in dataframe are "prodId" , "price" .....currently "price" stored in string , how to convert it Double with 6 precision?